# How to invoke a function inside another function in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I have recently started learning Common Lisp and noticed I really don't know how to invoke a user-defined function inside another function.

I can see that sometime **(funcall #'func ...)** works and sometimes **(funcall func ...)** depending whether *func* is passed as a parameter to the invoking function or defined inside *labels* etc.

So why this distinction? And is there a general rule as when to use **#'** and when not?

An example is the following short code that I wrote. Note the difference in the invocations of *get-next-token* and *reader-fun* function:

```
(defvar *end-of-file* (gensym "eof"))

(defun get-reader (reader-type)
  (case reader-type (:char-reader #'read-char)
                    (:line-reader #'read-line)
                    (:exp-reader  #'read)
                    (t (error "Unknown reader-type argument"))))

(defun read-all (filename reader-type)
  (let ((result '())
        (token  ""))
    (labels ((get-next-token (reader-fun stream)
               (funcall reader-fun stream nil *end-of-file*))
             (read-loop (reader-fun)
               (with-open-file (stream filename :direction :input)
                 (loop      
                   (setq token (funcall #'get-next-token
                                       reader-fun stream))
                   (if (eq token *end-of-file*)
                       (return (nreverse result))
                       (push token result))))))
        (read-loop (get-reader reader-type)))))
```

Comment: Although this has been closed, note that your `(funcall #'get-next-token ...)` is far better expressed as `(get-next-token ...)`.

Comment: Right! Within _labels_ I can actually invoke other functions - which are also defined inside _labels_ - directly. I totally missed this point.

Comment: And note that this is always true: `(funcall #'<x> ...)` is the same as `(<x> ...)`, except possibly in some weird cases.

Comment: @tfb I think the only weird case when both forms work is when `<x>` is not a symbol (ie it is a `setf` function or some implementation defined extension). If the symbol names a macro then the former would be an error and if it names a compiler macro then the compiler macro ought to run on both forms.